# How to do one line if condition assignment in Python

Tags: python

I am using two if conditions in the below code snippet. disable_env value can be passed as a parameter to a function or as an environment variable.
Is there a more efficient way to do this in Python using a single if statement?

```
def func(disable_env=False):
  if os.environ.get("DISABLE_ENV"):
     disable_env=True
  if not disable_env: 
     print("something")
```

Comment: Single if statement won't make this more efficient. It will however make it less readable. If you really want it will be somethong like `if not (disable_env := os.environ.get("DISABLE_ENV")): print("something")` using [Assignment Expressions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/)

Comment: `if 'DISABLE_ENV' not in os.environ and not disable_env: print('something')`

Comment: `print("something" if not os.environ.get("DISABLE_ENV") else "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def func(disable_env=False):    
    disable_env = os.environ.get("DISABLE_ENV", disable_env)
```

should do the trick.